# Adobe premier pro in window menu extension not showing/disable...?

Tags: adobe, adobe-premiere

Please provide soludion ...why this is disable show?how to **enable** this?
Adobe premiere pro in window menu extension not showing/disable...?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqszB.jpg)tps://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3V3f.jpg

Comment: you probably need to use extensions manager this https://install.anastasiy.com/ or https://www.myslingstudio.com/Help/KB/KB-1159.aspx